# Remove screen from stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I’ve observed Back button logic works seeing the sequence of screens in the stack. I’ve a Drawer navigator placed inside stack navigator.

On top of the stack I’ve Splash screen. On Dashboard when I press back button it takes me to splash screen.

How can I remove splash screen from stack after entering in the app, So when I press back button Dashboard it will EXIT the app instead of taking to SPLASH SCREEN.

```
/* @flow */

import React from "react";
import { Platform, Text } from "react-native";
import { Root } from "native-base";
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Available from "./components/Available";
import Splash from "./components/splash/“;
import SideBar from "./components/sidebar";
import Discover from "./components/Discover/";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/";
import Contact from "./components/Contact"



const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
    Discover: { screen: Discover },
    Contact: { screen: Contact},
      },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
   initialRouteName: "Dashboard",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);


const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
      Splash: { screen: Splash },
      Drawer: { screen: Drawer },                           
      Available: { screen: Available },
        Register: { screen: Register },
    },
    {
       //  initialRouteName: “Splash”,
         headerMode: "none",
    }
);

export default () =>
    <Root>
        <AppNavigator />
    </Root>;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One solution would be to reset the stack inside the splash screen component and redirect the user to the screen that you prefer:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Drawer'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

**For newer versions of `react-navigation`** :

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

[Link to the official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset)

Comment: but doing this will not remove splash screen from the stack. I want to EXIT the app on back press on the dashboard not to the splash screen navigating to some other screen.

Comment: this code will wipe all history so splash screen is not going to be part of the stack anymore

Comment: the link you provided is not valid, can you please provide a fixed link to the documentation

Comment: the link above is not valid for version 3 , use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781113/404339

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi updated my answer for the newer versions of react-navigation. Looks that some things changed since last year. So my answer is still valid

Answer (score 27):

One of the simplest solutions would be, replace current screen with new screen so user won't be allowed to go back.

```
const SplashScreen: () => {
    ...
  navigation.replace("LoginScreen"); // Move forward and Remove this screen from stack
```

see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 5):

In **react-navigation 5.x** version. If you want to open new screen and remove previous stack screen, you can write: -

```
navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('screen_name', {params: {}}));
```

The **replace** action allows to replace a route in the navigation state. You can import it as:-

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

If you want to perform other actions on stack navigation check out this link-
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions

Comment: Elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it using [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/802#issuecomment-296728810)

code:

```
const prevGetStateForActionHomeStack = HomeStack.router.getStateForAction;
HomeStack.router = {
  ...HomeStack.router,
  getStateForAction(action, state) {
    if (state && action.type === 'ReplaceCurrentScreen') {
      const routes = state.routes.slice(0, state.routes.length - 1);
      routes.push(action);
      return {
        ...state,
        routes,
        index: routes.length - 1,
      };
    }
    return prevGetStateForActionHomeStack(action, state);
  },
};
replaceScreen = () => {
  const { locations, position } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  this.props.navigation.dispatch({
    key: 'NearMeMap',
    type: 'ReplaceCurrentScreen',
    routeName: 'NearMeMap',
    params: { locations, position },
  });
};
```

Also if you need in-depth explanation of the code, watch this short video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XULdsZWowU&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  navigation.reset({
    index:0,
    routes:[
      {
        name:"Welcome",
      //  params:{key:'param'},
      },
    ],
  });
}, 1000);},[]);
```

You can also trigger the this onPress like:

```
onPress={()=>navigation.reset({
    index:0,
    routes:[
      {
        name:"NameOfScreen",
      //  params:{key:'param'},
      },
    ],
  })}
```