# Reactnavigation - Do not go back to login screen by pressing the back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The application returns to the login screen when you click the back button. I need it to simply close the application. The user opens the login screen to login. Once logged in, he can no longer return to the login screen. When you click the back button, it must exit the application.

I already searched for a solution on the web and did not find it. I found a way to clear the stack, but it only works if the route is inside StackNavigator. In my case the route is inside DrawerNavigator.

**my configuration**

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login, navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({ drawerLockMode:"locked-closed" })},
    ListCliente: { screen: ListCliente },  
    Sincronizacao: { screen: Sincronizacao },

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Login",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer }, 
    FormCliente: { screen: FormCliente },
    ListAtendimento: { screen: ListAtendimento },
    FormAtendimento: { screen: FormAtendimento },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Drawer",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);
```

A possible solution. But it only works if the route is inside StackNavigator. And the CustomerClient route is inside DrawerNavigator.

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'listCliente' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**summing up. I need to exit the login screen and go to the Customer list screen and not return to the login screen when I click the back button. Anyone know if they have this feature?**

Comment: you have to move it out from drawer.logically if you see actually you cannot remove the drawer from the stack to support other screens navigation. This worked for me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021546/remove-screen-from-stack-navigator

Comment: @devedv I will try to remove the login screen from the drawer. Many thanks for the reply. I had not thought of that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: "MainScreen"
      })
    ]
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

> Try this code snippet. It'll work.