# Remove navigation stack for login screen after user login

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, reset, react-navigation-stack

I am new to React Native. I am so confused about navigation stack.

Here is my code.

```
const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ title: 'login' }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'home' }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Users will see the login screen once they run this app.
And here is LogInScreen.

```
const LogInScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button 
        title="google login"
        onPress={() => 
          navigation.navigate('Home')
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Users is going to see home screen after they clicked login button.
But the problem is they still can see back button in home screen.
After log in , it's not necessary to show login screen to users.
Hence, I need to reset stack to remove back button in home screen.

Comment: Instead of stack navigation use switch navigation. It will switch between two pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the back button in the home screen, you can use the `headerLeft` option as specified [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#overriding-the-back-button).

I think it is enough if you're developing for iOS. For Android, the user can still use the back button to go back. I think resetting the stack and navigate the user the home page is also a good solution. You can look into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021546/remove-screen-from-stack-navigator)