# Prevent user from swipe back or using physical back button to go back to splash screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm having trouble with preventing user from going back to splash screen.
Previously when I was working with React Navigation 4 this is what I used

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "HomeScreen" })]
});
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

But in React Navigation 5 the I've tried the code below with no success:

```
const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [CommonActions.navigate({ name: screenName })]
});
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

or this:

```
navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: "HomeScreen" }]
});
```

I've also tried to set `gestureEnabled` to false in both `Stack.Screen` `options` props or in `Stack.Navigator` `screenOptions` props, but I can still swipe right to go back to splash screen.

Does anyone have any workaround for this?
Thank you.

Comment: find the answer that will really help you.
[prevent user to go back on splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66208340/5681567)

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide for authentication flows in the website, might be useful: [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow).